# Shell Scripting-Unable to assign random value to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying below script to generate and print IPs as per input given.But i am getting command not found after executing
Inputs:
enter IP: 155.169.10
range: 10
total: 4
Actual:
testing.sh: line 15: 155.55.10.11: command not found
testing.sh: line 15: 155.55.10.12: command not found
testing.sh: line 15: 155.55.10.13: command not found
testing.sh: line 15: 155.55.10.14: command not found
testing.sh: line 15: 155.55.10.15: command not found
Expected Result:
155.55.10.11
155.55.10.12
155.55.10.13
155.55.10.14

```
 #!/bin/bash
        echo "enter IP: xxx.xxx.xx"
        read ip;
        echo "enter range"
        read range;
        echo "total"
        read total;
        count=1
        while [ $count -le $total ];
        do
        num=$(expr $range + $count)
        #echo "$ip"".$num"
        IP=$("$ip"".$num")
        echo $IP
        count=$(expr $count + 1)
        done
```

Comment: Remove the subshell. `IP="$ip.$num"`

Comment: `expr` went the way of the Dodo a long time ago. Why not `num=$((range + count))` and `((count++))`? (that will eliminate two-subshells you spawn every iteration)

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you so much for your time. Its working now.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin- Thanks David. I made the changes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, remove the unneeded subshell - `IP="$ip.$num"`

Since it's `bash`, you can also benefit from some performance tweaks. Try this -

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i range total num count=1
read -p "enter IP: xxx.xxx.xx: " ip;
read -p "enter range: " range;
read -p "total: " total;
while (( count < total ));
do  num=$(( range + count++ ))
    IP="$ip.$num"
    echo "$IP"
done
```

I leave validation of inputs as another question. :)

## Update

Ok, for the fun of it...
This should validate the inputs themselves -

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i count node
read -p "enter starting IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: " ip;
IFS=. read -a node <<< "$ip"
for n in 0 1 2 3
do if [[ -n "${node[4]}" || -z "${node[$n]}" || "${node[$n]}" =~ [^0-9] ]] || (( ${node[$n]} > 255 ))
   then echo "Invalid IP '$ip'"
        exit 1
   fi
done
base="${ip%.*}"
node="${ip##*.}"
read -p "How many do you want? " count;
while (( count-- ));
do  echo "$base.$node"
    (( node++ ))
done
```

That still allows the IP's created to be invalid, such as if you start with IP 1.2.3.250 and ask for 10 more. Considering writing a check for that too, lol

Comment: Thanks again Paul.Code is clean.Much useful :)